# CPanel Email Configurations

Tags: cpanel, cpanel-xmlapi

How do I configure an email address using cpanel to bounce back incoming emails after a certain date?
Our Organization wants to receive quotations from potential firms upto a certain defined date. After the date line, our organization wants the email account to automatically bounce back anyone sendind in late quotations.

Comment: Does quotations email has common Subject?

Comment: @SachinG., No. The subject is not common. But is there a way?

Comment: Yes if the subject has fixed lines then there’s a workaround. I’ll post solution as per your need in few minutes :)

Comment: You can certainly do that with Cron Jobs OR custom Exim Rules but for that you should have root access to the server. Do you have root access to the server?